# Python: Necessito obter a área abaixo de uma curva

Tags: python, array, numpy, matplotlib

Este é o meu código:

```
index = 0

T = np.zeros((300,1))

T[:,0] = np.linspace(0.01, 3, 300)[:]

A = np.loadtxt('AAA_'+str(index)+'.txt')

Tr = 1.0

idx = (abs(T-(Tr))).argmin()

a = T[:idx+1]

a = [i[0] for i in a]

b = A[:idx+1]

area = np.trapz(a, b)

        
plt.plot(T, A)

plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu objetivo é obter a área assinalada a vermelho na figura, sendo que não conheço a função que define a curva azul. Tentei integrar usando a regra dos trapézios, no entanto sem sucesso. O que estou a fazer mal? Alguma sugestão para tentar resolver este problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: [Isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320262/calculating-the-area-under-a-curve-given-a-set-of-coordinates-without-knowing-t) ajuda?

Comment: @PauloMarques Ajudou sim! Muito obrigado pela atenção!!!